# 2D graphics in Java maze

Tags: java, jframe, graphics2d, illegalargumentexception, maze

I am trying to give 2d graphics in my maze but i have this Kind of Error
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

```
public class Exercise extends JFrame {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Maze");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
     frame.add(new Exercise());
    frame.setVisible(true);
  Mazes();
}


public static boolean[][]  Mazes() throws IOException {
```

What changes i should do to have the right result ?

Comment: `frame.add(new Exercise());` <- You can't add a window to a window

Comment: How can i add my public static boolean[][]  Mazes() ?

Comment: or what should i add in the add to work ? sorry for asking but i am completly newbie

Comment: Your `Exercise` **is** a `JFrame`. You can't add a JFrame to another JFrame. You could fix this by extending `JPanel` instead for example

Comment: I want to work with JFrame what should i change ?

Comment: As @QBrute wrote use `Exercise extends JPanel`, so `new Exercise()`   will construct a `JPanel`. The `JPanel` will be added to `JFrame frame = new JFrame("Maze");`